# Detect messages dropped by ros2 bag record

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Platform: Ubuntu 20.04
- ROS version: ROS2 foxy

I'm using `ros2 bag record` to record data published by my own nodes. I know the expected message rate of my nodes and can therefore calculate the expected number of messages in the bag file given the "duration" and "message count" provided by `ros2 bag info`.

My node publishes data on a single topic. When I run a single node and record the data published on its topic, I'm getting the expected number of messages in the bag file. If I instantiate two nodes and record the data from both topics, there are less messages in the bag file than expected.

I'm assuming this is some performance issue as the data rate of such a topic is rather high (~120 MB/s). Before starting to tune performance, I want to find a reliable way to detect if `ros2 bag record` is unable to record any of the incoming data. For my application, dropping data is not allowed and therefore this needs to be at least detected to avoid ending up with a bag file with missing data.

Is there any way to detect messages being dropped by `ros2 bag record`? Can this be somehow controlled by setting QoS appropriately? I have tried setting QoS of my publishing node to `KeepAll` but this has not prevented drops.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391514/detect-messages-dropped-by-ros2-bag-record/) by [simong](https://answers.ros.org/users/84210/simong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2021-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve this issue by overriding the QoS settings of `ros2 bag record` by using the `--qos-profile-overrides-path` option. I'm using the following QoS settings for each topic I'm recording:

```
<topic name>:
  durability: volatile
  history: keep_all
  reliability: reliable
```

The QoS of my publishers is `rclcpp::QoS(10)`. Using these QoS overrides prevents `ros2 bag record` to drop any messages.

Note that the `ros2 bag` performance of the `foxy` package is not very good. This will cause the data to pile up in memory if `ros2 bag record` is not able to save to disk quickly enough, eventually running out of memory. To solve this issue, use `ros2 bag` from the `foxy-future` branch, see https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/tree/foxy-future

---

Originally posted by [simong](https://answers.ros.org/users/84210/simong/) with karma: 41 on 2021-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1